# Set 3D object behind the real world in Vuforia Augmented Reality

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm using `Vuforia` SDK for `Unity3D` in my AR application. The scenario of the app is similar to [this demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bCcvEVyAXQ0):

When marker is recognized, the wall with some image on it (like a press wall) and different 3D objects in front of it should appear.

My problem is that I need this wall to be behind the physical world, so that a person standing on the physical marker could see the wall behind him and the rest 3D content in front of him. 
I'm not sure if I can use `Vuforia Smart Terrain` feature, or can I make something like a room (with one wall) with Unity only?

I'd so appreciate if you could give me any resources to read or any ideas on the implementation.

Comment: You'd have to look into occlusion. I don't think Vuforia does that apart from the 3d marker object, I could be wrong.It would also have great impact on what device can run since it would be quite performance demanding.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It will run on PC. Could you give more information about occlusion?

Comment: You would need some sort of sensor. like the Kinnect. That way you could detect people and other objects and not draw your 3D Objects on top of them. If it has to be mobile i recommend using Google Tango, since that sensor is inbuilt.

Comment: Well, I need only one object to be behind everything - the wall. Are you sure it can't be done with Unity?

Comment: Yup, pretty sure :)

Comment: If your wall is the marker then Vuforia should be able to use that item for occlusion. Other environment items will most likely not be considered (that is the part I am not 100% sure). See this example where the ball hides behind the cylinder marker https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YIA07cE_5s4

Comment: Actually, a simple way is to set the position of the marker on the wall. Then create a virtual wall that is a duplicate of the wall in the Unity scene. Using shader, that wall is not visible but it will occlude whatever is behind. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/316064/can-i-obscure-an-object-using-an-invisible-object.html